# Python multiprocessing - Asynchronous communication between Parent and many Child processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to write script using subprocess workers to download many files at once. Whole process would look somewhat like that:

```
Manager Process
├ Worker
├ Worker
├ Worker
└ Worker
```

I've achieved something like that using `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` with links to files created in Manager Process, while workers were `get()`ing files urls from it. Whole process was runnig untill Queue was empty, but there was no way to for example pause downloading. Now I'm trying to create async communication between Parent and Child processes so I could do somethin like that:

```
Worker » Manager: "Give me new link"
Manager » Worker: Gives new link
(Worker starts downloading)
```

or:

```
Worker » Manager: "Give me new link"
Manager » Worker: "Wait for now"
(Worker is waiting)
Manager » Worker: "I've got new job for you"
(Worker starts downloading)
```

Add to that more workers and we have:

```
Worker1 » Manager: "Give me new link"
Worker2 » Manager: "Give me new link"
Manager » Worker1: Gives new link
(Worker1 starts downloading)
Manager » Worker2: Gives new link
(Worker2 starts downloading)
```

Unfortunetly I don't know how to achieve such communication and I'd like to use pure `multiprocessing` without external packages so I could easly use my script on other machines. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
The real problem is:
I'm looking for effective way of communicating between processes. If one process receives msgs from many processes, it needs to infinitely loop over every connection to check if there is msg pending. Is there a way for process to wait/freeze for msg from any of child processes?

Comment: you will have to use system signaling, but that is more thought to stop/terminate processes. Any fine grained process steering, you will have to manage by a task-queue, where each worker listens to and retrieves tasks from, as they are issued (download-link-http::xxx, cancel-now, download-link-htttp:yyy); this goes into the direction of process-messaging

Comment: How do you handle your "download"? Is there any other way to stop your download than to kill the process? Is your downloader blocking in a IO call waiting for it to complete, or does it loop through something so that you can actually have your code executed while downloading?

Comment: @MarcelZoll I was thinking about creating connections for each worker using Pipe and use it to exchange messages, but this way Manager would need to check in loop if there is any msg from any of workers

Comment: What would be the "messages"?  Is it only "give me more work - here is more work" and "terminate what you are currently doing"?  Or could there be other communication as well?

Comment: @Hannu For now I was thinking something like pause = finish downloading but don't start next one.  And to earlier question, I'm downloading and writing data in chunks so there should be no blocking if I wanted to pause during download.

Comment: does it need to work on windows?

Comment: Not really, it can work only on linux.

Comment: I'm looking for effective way of communicating between processes. If one process receives msgs from many processes, it needs to infinitely loop over every connection to check if there is msg pending. Is there a way for process to wait/freeze for msg from any of child processes?

Comment: There is no such way. You need to either import modules (zeromq would  probably help but there are others) or you need to loop somewhere. You can only decide what your loop actually does - are you checking for multiple queues or pipes, or are you managing your internal task list and executing tasks from it or shutting them down. The killer here is the need to interrupt a task. Without this it would be a typical use case for a `Pool()` but as you need to intervene with a running task, this is out. You need to write your own version of pool with this functionality.

Comment: If all you do in your different processes, is downloading files, you should look into using threads instead, since they allow yo uto communicate much easier as they share common variables and the like. Downloading files tend to be IO bound, so you would likely still get a nice speed-up since you won't be hindered by the GIL.